# Share cache between distinct jobs

Tags: github, caching, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have two jobs in the same GitHub Actions workflow. The first one creates a file and the second one expects to find this file in the same directory where the first one created it.

I thought I can use `actions/cache@v3` for it like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: some_dir/my_file
          key: my_file

      ... (create the file)

  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: some_dir/my_file
          key: my_file

      ... (use the file)
```

GitHub Action says that cache is restored successfully in `job2`, however, in `job2` I can't find `my_file` in the directory where I expect it to be. What is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the problem was actually that I used to look for cache in path relative to custom `working-directory` while steps with `uses` are not influenced by this setting, so I had to use absolute paths for `actions/cache`.

```
# In the first job
- uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: <path to the files you need>  # Note that this path is not influenced by working-directory set in defaults, for example
    key: some-key

# In the second job
- uses: actions/cache@v3
  with:
    path: <path to the files you need>  # See the note below
    key: some-key  # Must be the same key you specified in the first job
```

Now it works as expected.

*Note*: I'm not sure if the same files must be specified in the second job as in the first one. In one of my projects specifying only the subset I need works fine, while in the other I have to specify exactly the same files in both jobs.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide the syntax of how to use the dir cached in one job in the other job, do we need to use needs.job1.<id>.output ? Or is there much eaiser way to do that?

Comment: @wehelpdox No, there is no need to use `needs` like this. You just cache the dir with `actions/cache@v3` using the same code (the same path and the same key) in both jobs

Comment: Hi, how to add  [ if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' ] in Job 1 to be verified if the cache exists in Job 2 ? Do we need to send the cache as output in Job 1 and use it in Job 2?

Comment: Can you provide the code? I not following you and having the same problem

Comment: @camiloposada Added a code snippet